# Cannot connect live mysql database in local server, hosted in google cloud hosting

Tags: mysql, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am unable to connect the live mysql database in local server, hosted in cloud hosting. I am not getting a place to set the host url in Remote MySql as I am not having cPanel. Please give suggestion to set the host url, such that I can set the db settings properly in local and access the live database. Currently my project is not running due to improper db setting.

Answer (score 0):

Live MYSQL database can only be connected if you have proper rights from the CPanel. You must have a static ip on local/Remote machine to connect to the Remote mysql. This permission Can be configured only if you have access to CPanel. Remote database Authenticates the local Machine using IP address of the machine if you want to connect from Local machine you must buy a static IP address and then in CPanel 
 databases >> Remote MYSQL >> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grzWI.png)

Enter your IP address you will have instant access to MYSQL remote database Until your IP address isn't changed. Now connect by giving IP address of your server as HOST and then the database name with Password you are successfully connected.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is hosted locally on the server , you do not need to enter any URL for it. Just use localhost as the DB host and it should work correctly.